# How to call an instance method on an instance of a class from a different class

Tags: ruby

So I have the following setup

```
class foo
    :attr_accessor :textBoxInFoo

    @textBoxInFoo

    def appendText
        //appends text to textBoxInFoo
    end

    def getLastPartOfText
        //gets the last line of text in textBoxInFoo
    end
end

class bar
    def UseFoo
        //Declares instance of textBoxInFoo
    end
end

class snafu
     def runInBackground
         //Needs to read and write from instance of textBoxInFoo in bar class
     end
end
```

What I'm failing to grasp is how to do what I need to do in runInBackground to get it to read and write to textBoxInFoo, I've been reading through various explanations of instance and class methods, and none of them have really clicked with me yet, so I'm wondering if anyone knows what I'm messing up.

Comment: This is a little muddled you keep talking about instances of textBoxInFoo but there doesn't appear to be such a class. How do these classes relate to each other ? Also your code as is isn't valid ruby - that may be tangential to your question but it's definitely a distraction

Comment: Normally, you create an instance of a class (i.e. Now an object of that class) and that instance can use the instance variables and methods of that class. In your case, you're trying to access an instance variable within another class, `snafu`. But in order to access `@textBoxInFoo`, you should instantiate an instance of class `foo` first. So for example, within `runInBackground`, you would create a new instance `text = foo.new` and then you can access the instance variable `text.textBoxInFoo`.

Comment: In `RunInBackground` you can create a local reference to the other object with `Foo.new.textBoxInFoo`. If you don't want to initialize `Foo` then you can make a `Foo::TextBoxInFoo` constant. By the way your class names do need to start with capitals.

Answer (score 1):

This is a small example of how you can create a user object and send it to student object as an argument. run() method calls user's run method.

```
class User

  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize(name) # it is similar to constructor
    @name = name
  end

  #run method
  def run
    puts "I am running"
  end

  #getter for name
  def get_name
    @name
  end

  #setter for name
  def set_name=(name)
    @name = name
  end
end


class Student

  attr_accessor :obj
  def initialize(obj)
    @obj = obj

  end

  def run
    obj.run
    puts "inside of Student"
  end
end

user = User.new("John")
stud = Student.new(user)
stud.run # shows I am running
         #       inside of student
```